# Can't get second scroll down arrow to stay where I want it

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, css-position

Site URL: [www.awarecanada.com](http://www.awarecanada.com)
Passcode to site is: Woods

The first scroll down arrow on the page is fixed in its position but the second one on the "new releases" section moves (despite using the same coding) depending on screen size, why is this happening and how do I get it to stay just above the bottom of the image?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the arrows inside the element that they need to be relative too rather than in the BODY. It'll be a thousand times easier to align them exactly then!

current xpath -> `/html/body/div[2]`

Suggested xpath -> `/html/body/div[2]/main/article/section[2]/div[3]`

then, using your existing CSS with a few changes

```css
.scroll-down2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
    border-right: 3px solid white;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
    animation: fade_move_down 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

demo with resizing

[image: Resizing browser window]

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your response! 

This is exactly what I'm after, what you're saying makes sense but where do I change the path to correct this? Do you know if Squarespace would allow this?

Comment: I'm not sure about squarespace, sorry. 
Try and edit that section to see if you can add custom html there, the arrow just needs to be within that section rather than just floating around in the body, additionally, you should do the same for the first arrow.

Comment: I’m not so well versed with html & css, especially regarding xpath. I get what you’re saying technically but just don’t know how to implement it, not sure where exactly to replace the xpath with the one you suggested. 

By any chance could you show me what you did step by step, maybe that could help? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Well your website 2nd arrow is moving because of this `animation : fade_move_down 4s ease-in-out infinite` and just change its `top` property value to `1450px` for desktop view